# Multiple default values specified for column "id" of the table

Tags: python, django, database, postgresql, django-models

I use to run my website on my laptop and its database was Sqlite, recently I wanted to transfer it to DigitalOcean and I changed its database to Postgresql, but when I migrate I encounters with some problems.

Python 3.4
Django 1.8

## Error

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "profiles_userprofile"
```

## My Model

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=get_image_path, default='/static/image/avatar/male.png')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=4, validators=[MinValueValidator(3), MaxValueValidator(99)])
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try explicitly specifying the `id` field and marking it as the primary key:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    avatar = models.ImageField(blank=True, upload_to=get_image_path, default='/static/image/avatar/male.png')
    age = models.IntegerField(default=4, validators=[MinValueValidator(3), MaxValueValidator(99)])
```

Django should automatically create a sequence for this field.

It may be that the `User` foreign key without an explicitly defined primary key is confusing the ORM, although that's just a theory.

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing locally, and don't care about your migration history, and you just need a quick-fix, you could do this:

```
manage.py migrate <your app name> zero
```

Then delete the migration files except for the `__init__.py` in `<your app name>`.

Finally:

```
manage.py makemigrations <your app name>
manage.py migrate
```

A more complicated approach would be learning [how to write and modify migration files to populate existing rows](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/howto/writing-migrations/#migrations-that-add-unique-fields).