# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "_id" of table "Asset_movie"

Tags: python, django, postgresql-10

After make migrations , i tried to do migrate, but i am getting the django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "_id" of table "Asset_movie"

```
from django.db import models
import date time
from django.contrib import admin

class Movie(models.Model):   
        CHOICES_MOVIE_TYPE = (
             ("SF", 'Short-Film'),
             ("P", "Promo"),
             ("OT", 'Other'),
         );
           CHOICES_LANGUAGE_TYPE = (
               (" ", ''),

           );
           CHOICES_ORIGINAL_OWNER_TYPE = (
               ("OT", 'Other'),

           );
           CHOICES_REMARK_TYPE = (

           );
          # _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
           name = models.CharField(max_length = 50, blank = False)
           Movie_Type = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = CHOICES_MOVIE_TYPE, default = "OT", blank = False)
           language = models.CharField(max_length = 5, choices=CHOICES_LANGUAGE_TYPE, default = "OT", blank = False)enter code here
           tags = models.TextField()
           original_owner = models.CharField(max_length = 2, choices = CHOICES_ORIGINAL_OWNER_TYPE, default = "OT", blank = False)
           Partner = models.CharField(max_length = 10)
           acquisition_cost = models.DecimalField(max_digits = 5, decimal_places = 4,  blank = True)
           release_date = models.DateField(("Date"), default = datetime.date.today)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964936/multiple-default-values-specified-for-column-id-of-the-table possible duplicate?

Comment: @ Martin Stoyanov,thanks for your response, i tried what you said , but it is not working .