# Multiple default values specified for column "id"

Tags: django, database, postgresql, sqlite

I use to run my website on my laptop and its database was Sqlite, recently I wanted to transfer it to DigitalOcean and I changed its database to Postgresql, but when I migrate I encounters with some problems.

My Model

```
class Profil_Eleve(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    statut = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    telephone = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Neant")
    niveau = models.CharField(max_length=250)
    ecole = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Neant")
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="Neant")
    eleve_or_etudiant = models.CharField(max_length=250, default="eleve")

Exception:

    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 323, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 364, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 83, in wrapped
    res = handle_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/migrate.py", line 234, in handle
    fake_initial=fake_initial,
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 117, in migrate
    state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
    state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/executor.py", line 245, in apply_migration
    state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/migration.py", line 124, in apply
    operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/migrations/operations/fields.py", line 112, in database_forwards
    field,
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 447, in add_field
    self.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/base/schema.py", line 137, in execute
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 99, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 67, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 76, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "/home/abdoulaye/schoollife/venv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 84, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "eleve_profil_eleve"
```

I don't know what to do

Comment: Can you please show the full traceback?

Comment: How did you migrate the data from SQLite to PostreSQL?

Comment: I install psycopg2==2.8.2,create a database name schoollife and modify my settings.py :for deleting sqlite and adding postgresql

Comment: possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964936/multiple-default-values-specified-for-column-id-of-the-table