# django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table

Tags: django, django-migrations

I am 'Dockerizing' my Django project and I am facing the following issue when applying migrations on my container:

```sh
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: multiple default values specified for column "id" of table "web_accountant"
```

This is my model:

```py
from django.contrib.auth.models import User


class Accountant(User):
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

I tried adding `id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key = True)` as suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30964936/multiple-default-values-specified-for-column-id-of-the-table) with no success.

I also tried extending the Django User model another way (one to one field) but the error persists.

What am I doing wrong here?

## EDIT:

I fixed this by resetting the migration files and `web_account` table.

Comment: Please remove the migrations (and the `web_account` table) and try to create new migration files. It is likely that by adding/removing `id` fields, the migrations are a bit "mixed up".

Comment: Genius! It worked. Thank you for the prompt answer.